# How to count by Month in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My question is how to get total number of id's created per month. The below is my code fetching response from Mysql Db.

```
const dashboardOverview = async (req,res,next) => {
 var ordersPerMonth = await Orders.findAll({attributes:['od_id','od_created_date']});
     for(var i = 0; i < ordersPerMonth.length ; i++){
        let dataItem = {};
        for(const [key,value] of Object.entries(ordersPerMonth[i].dataValues)){
            dataItem[key.replace("od_","")] = value;
        }
        dataStore.push(dataItem);
    }
    console.log(dataStore)

    const arr = dataStore;
    console.log(arr)
    const counts = arr.reduce((m, { created_date }) => {
        // Create a key from the year and month, eg "2021-08"
        const key = created_date.substr(0, 7)
        
        // Increment the count for the key
        return m.set(key, (m.get(key) ?? 0) + 1)
      }, new Map())
      
      console.log(Object.fromEntries(counts))
}
```

Now in response I wanted monthname and total count of orders placed that month. For ex- [ January-21 : 23, February-21: 45......December-21: 56]
But while using reduce() function I am getting type error:arr.reduce is not a function.
I hope my query is clear.

Comment: Just month (in any year) or month and year?

Comment: For eg . Jan : 4, Feb : 6 , ..... Dec : 7

Comment: What I mean is if you have say 4 for "Jan 2021" and 2 for "Jan 2020", is that 6 for "Jan" or are the per-year counts separate?

Comment: As of now current year i.e 2021

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. If you have `[{ id: 1, created_date: "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z" }, { id: 2, created_date: "2021-01-01T00:00:00Z" }]`, what should the expected result be (note one date is in 2020, the other in 2021)?

Comment: Ok so basically orders places per month of a year is what I wanted. Suppose 5 orders placed in january,2 in feb... So in response I wanted "monthname : ordercount" for the whole running year 2021.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236831/discussion-between-nikeeta-kurrey-and-phil).

Comment: Are you using Sequelize? If so, what DBMS? You can probably just do a `GROUP BY` query with `COUNT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of result can be achieved by [*reducing*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) your array to a [*map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of month counts.

```js
const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en", {
  year: "2-digit",
  month: "long",
})

const formatKey = date => formatter.format(date).replace(" ", "-")

const dashboardOverview = async (req, res, next) => {
  const orders = await Orders.findAll({
    attributes: ["od_id", "od_created_date"]
  })

  const ordersPerMonth = orders.reduce((map, { od_created_date }) => {
    // assuming od_created_date is already a `Date` instance
    const key = formatKey(od_created_date).replace(" ", "-")

    return map.set(key, (map.get(key) ?? 0) + 1)
  }, new Map())

  const asObject = Object.fromEntries(ordersPerMonth)

  console.log(asObject)

  // and if you want to respond with JSON
  res.json(asObject)
}
```

Comment: Hi Phil, the problem is I am getting the response as Json object so when i try to use created_date.substr() it is throwing type error.

Comment: There seems to be something missing from your question then. Could you please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69083208/edit) to show a real code example of how you fetch / receive / produce your data?

Comment: sure i'll edit the question for a clear understanding. Actually I am new to Nodejs.

Comment: Hi Phil,can you try now? @Phil

Comment: @Nikeetakurrey I've update my answer. Note that it's quite different now

Comment: Thanks alot Phil. Thats exactly what I wanted :-). @Phil

Comment: TypeError: map.get is not a function

Comment: @AbbasGhaith with the code in my answer that is literally impossible. I suggest asking your own question with as much detail as possible